# javascriptのexportとimportの使い方

Tags: javascript, es6

```
// ./hoge.js
class HOGE {}
class FUGA {}
class PIYO {}
```

↑このようなファイルを作り

```
// ./fuga.js
import * from './hoge';
// ↑↓ どちらでも可能なように
import {HOGE, FUGA, PIYO} from 'hoge';
```

↑このように使えるようにしたいのですが、`./hoge.js`側ではどのように`export`するのがよいのでしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

```
export class HOGE {}
export class FUGA {}
export class PIYO {}
```

といった具合に各classをexportしていくのが無難かと思います。